# How to hide/show formview?

Tags: asp.net

I want to get the current value in `formview1`; if it is 0, I want to hide `formview1`, and if it is greater than 0 display it.

How can I do that?

My code is as follows:

```
<asp:FormView ID="FormView4" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource5">
    <ItemTemplate>
        Short/Over/Under Paid : 
        <asp:Label ID="Column1Label" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Column1") %>' />                                        
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:FormView>
```

Comment: **aspx code :**
        <asp:FormView ID="FormView4" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource5">
          <ItemTemplate>
            Short/Over/Under Paid : 
            <asp:Label ID="Column1Label" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Column1") %>' />                                        
          </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:FormView>

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To edit information into your post please use the [edit] button. Here is some documentation about So policy [tour], [ask],[mcve],

Comment: For the sake of an exemple, you can use `Bind("Column1")` or `Eval("Column1")`. But please in this code is not for the exemple Use `((DataRowView)Container.DataItem)["Column1"]`, Ok It's longer to write but it's cleaner faster and predictable. While Eval and Bind, can do some magic trick and give you an unexpected result instead of telling you that you make a typo in your column name.